# Как добавить .class в существующий проект в Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, классы

Добрый день! Перешёл с BlueJ на Eclipse и никак не удаётся добавить файл, к примеру, `p.class` в новый проект на Eclipse (в BlueJ можно было просто скинуть в папку с проектом). Перечитал десятки рекомендаций по использованию Build Path - Add Class Folder и ничего не помогло. Если возможно - как-то пошагово для чайника объяснить, как присоединить файл `p.class` к новому проекту, скажем, Polygon? Спасибо.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в java файлы с расширением class добавлять в проект не нужно, они генерируются компилятором. .

Answer (score 1):

Меню Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries, кнопки справа Add Class Folder/Add External Class Folder. Соответственно, необходимо указать папку где лежит ваш class файл. Вообще странно что вам потребовалось добавить именно class файл, а не какой-нибудь jar с библиотекой. Если этот class-файл ваш, т.е. вы его сделали самостоятельно, то гораздо удобнее подключить ваш проект с исходниками этого класса. В том же диалоговом окне закладка Projects.